# Material UI Button contained style not working with Transition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

### Current Behavior

When having a `Button` with a "contained" variant in a `Transition` (`Slide`, `Grow` or `Fade`) the `Button`'s variant is no longer recognized.

### Expected Behavior

The `Button` should have a background color.

### Steps to Reproduce

```
`import { ButtonGroup, Button, Slide } from '@material-ui/core';`
          <ButtonGroup variant="text" color="primary" aria-label="menu" id="buttongroup">
            {sections.map(x => <Button onClick={() => window.location.href = `#${x.name.toLowerCase()}`} key={x.name}>{x.name}</Button>)}
            <Button onClick={() => window.open('tel:00918779839201')}>(+91) 8779839201</Button>
            <Slide
              direction="left"
              in={useScrollTrigger({threshold: document.documentElement.clientHeight/1.5})}
              mountOnEnter
              unmountOnExit
            >
              <Button variant="contained">Schedule Site Visit</Button>
            </Slide>
          </ButtonGroup>
```

You can see an example [here](https://lodhamara.online/ange/).
Just scroll down and you'll see the Button sliding in on the top right of the Appbar.

Comment: I've [re-created your situation](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ardinghelli-yi2oz) and it works fine. What version of Material-ui do you have? Could you provide whole component? As I can see your button (on linked website) does not contain `.MuiButton-contained`.

Comment: @Jax-p I got MUI 4.9.5 and the code I wrote above is exactly what I have. I saw that the MuiButton-contained class is not there and that's exactly what I don't get as it definitely is in my code.

Comment: I've just updated dependency in provided example on MUI 4.9 and it still works. Problem has to be somewhere else. As I see the button has `grouped` variant. What's above the code you have provided?

Comment: @Jax-p I edited my question to show more code. When I remove <Slide> the variant="contained" shows. It only disappears when I add <Slide>. Here is a screenshot without the <Slide>: https://lodhamara.online/ange/screenshot.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ButtonGroup` assumes that its direct children are `Button` elements. Unless the child has the `variant` prop specified, `ButtonGroup` will [give the child its own variant](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.7/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonGroup/ButtonGroup.js#L226). In your case, you have a child that is a `Slide` element and that `Slide` element does not have a variant specified, so `ButtonGroup` gives it one (`text` in your case). `Slide` [passes this property on](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.7/packages/material-ui/src/Slide/Slide.js#L220) to the element it wraps and thus overrides the `variant` of your `contained` `Button`.

You can overcome this by specifying the variant on the `Slide` element:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import ButtonGroup from "@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";

export default function App() {
  const [slideIn, setSlideIn] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <ButtonGroup variant="text">
      <Button onClick={e => setSlideIn(true)}>Slide In</Button>
      <Button onClick={e => setSlideIn(false)}>Slide Out</Button>
      <Slide
        variant="contained"
        direction="left"
        in={slideIn}
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
      >
        <Button variant="contained">Schedule Site Visit</Button>
      </Slide>
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Slide contained Button]